# Nginx redirect to main domain on SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have two equal domains, served by virtual hosts, `site.com` and `additional.com`. I only have an SSL cert for the first one and don't really want it for another. When user is trying to log in, i'm doing a permanent redirect:

```
server {
  listen   443;
  server_name  additional.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://site.com permanent;
}
```

...

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site.com additional.com;

  root /home/site/production/public;

  location / {
    ...
  }
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name site.com;
  ssl                  on;
  ...
}
```

And that fails, since i get SSL traffic proxied to uplink server, and it cannot handle it, because it only talks HTTP and there's `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol` (for Chrome; Firefix and curl have slightly different error messages).
So I had to change it to (notice http, not https here):

```
server {
  listen   443;
  server_name  additional.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://site.com permanent;
}
```

Errors no longer appear, but when going to /login page (that should be secure and uplink redirects to HTTPS) it's not rewriting, stating that certificate is invalid. If you confirm security exception, you are then redirected to `site.com` landing page and need to click on `login` link for the second time.

How to set up a redirect from `https://additional.com/login` to point to `https://site.com` correctly?

Comment: No idea why this topic was closed. There's a bunch of nginx config related questions out there (see 'Related' section to the right). Solution isn't straightforward, and I tend to think it's a good idea to share it here. If there are any concrete problems with the way question is written, please let me know or feel free to rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that all `443` should be `443 ssl` and rewrite works (thanks @Sebastien for pointing out to `/$1`):

```
server {
  listen   443 ssl;
  server_name  additional.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://site.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a SSL certificate for every step of the journey if you want to redirect from HTTPS to HTTPS, I'm afraid. no way around it - at least to kill your errors.

That said... Try this for all your rewrites:

```
rewrite ^/(.*) https://site.com/$1 permanent;
```

This should keep the path used.

Comment: Figured out that i was listening on SSL port 443 with SSL off. Thanks for `$/1`, works like a charm.